# How to inject javascript interface in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am loading a page in webview in android. The page has an element(button) with the following code, NB:- It is a third party website and I have no control over the code shown here :-

```
    <i class="icon close cardClose" role="button" title="Close recently linked screen" tabindex="0"></i>
```

I want to add a javascript interface as in the below method :-

```
private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            view.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
            {
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void performClick() throws Exception
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, "login");
            return true;
        }
    }


mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
```

But the problem is that webview source code says :-

```
* @param object the Java object to inject into this WebView's JavaScript
     *               context. Null values are ignored.
     * @param name the name used to expose the object in JavaScript
     */
    public void addJavascriptInterface(Object object, String name) {
        checkThread();
        mProvider.addJavascriptInterface(object, name);
    }
```

The button doesnot seem to have an attribute named "name". Please throw some insight into the same if some one has knowledge.

Comment: you need to pass JavascriptInterface object name from which we can access the methods

Comment: @RahulKhurana How to get that name?

Comment: I would not use an anonymous inner class. All examples for `addJavascriptInterface()` I know use a named class.

Answer (score 0):

I recommed you to use it this way

```
view.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterfaceNew(getActivity(), this), "Android_Normal_Test");
```

and here `JavaScriptInterfaceNew` is your class name and `Android_Normal_Test` will be your object when you need to pass some event from `webview` to your `activity class`

Comment: Please make the answer more clear and please stick to the example code given in the question. I am not an expert in java script, that is why.

Comment: Ok. You want to execute performClick method?

Comment: Yes, I want to execute performClick method of button with in the html code I have asked in the question.

Comment: okk then with javascript event just use **login.performClick();**

Comment: I dont have control in the code that is loaded in the webview. It is coming from else where.

Comment: then how can you suppose to get any event from the webview. In this case your question is totally irrelevant

Comment: If there was an attribute with key "name", I should have been able to do it. But since that attribute is not there for the button, that is the problem.

Comment: then you can't control without any code modification in your html. you must have to insert javascript somehow in it